# Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC in j2ee

Tags: mysql

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3170)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3099)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1169)
at com.rings.dao.ConnectionHandler.SelectQuery_AllData(ConnectionHandler.java:376)
at com.rings.model.Model_Ring_Home.getSavedRings(Model_Ring_Home.java:49)
at com.rings.controller.Servlet_Ring_Save.processRequest(Servlet_Ring_Save.java:66)
at com.rings.controller.Servlet_Ring_Save.doGet(Servlet_Ring_Save.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

null

SELECT r.`ring_id`, r.`ring_name` FROM saved_rings AS s LEFT JOIN ring_master AS r ON s.`ring_id` = r.`ring_id` WHERE s.`user_id`=1;



1
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can't check now, but I think it should be [...]WHERE s.user_id="1";

Comment: U have listed all the output information from the sytem, before writing query directly in the java, implement the query in DB server and then start  to write it in programming code , it will be munch easier to identify the queries,, Try to explain in ur own words will help users to understand the quest easier ..

Comment: @EarlGrey : i tried that but it gave same error.

Comment: @TheUnusual : yup i implement the query in DB server but it works perfectly but when i tried with servlet than it didnt work. and yup i will try to explain in my own words. thanx..

Comment: Then post your code here .and notify the line that your are getting error it would be useful for all ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the java code and check that the query is passed correctly, especially in the case you use the query more than once.
Posting the java code would help.